# How to use Windows' Thread Priority Classes properly / Boost::Thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, macos, boost

I'm currently working on a class that aims at supporting thread priorities for my boost::threads. I've already implemented the code for OSX. I Need 9 priorities so I spread the values smoothly between 15 and 47 (because pthread's sched_get_priority_min/max on OSX returns 15 and 47). Now to the Windows part. How do you recommend to use the priority classes and their respective priority values from IDLE, LOWEST, BELOW_NORMAL ... up to TIME_CRITICAL? By now I'm tending to go with changing the priority classes over changing the priority values because I think the latter might be too fine grained. On the other hand, the THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL values might be dangerously high in the REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS. Maybe doing a little mix of both could be the right way to do it?
Further I'm wondering which priority class and priority value a common boost::thread has - Am I right in assuming NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS and THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL?

Thanks alot!

Comment: The proper way of using thread priorities is not using them at all 99% of the time, and in the remaining 1% you will want BELOW_NORMAL most of the time, and IDLE in some exceptional cases. User code has no justifiable reason for TIME_CRITICAL or REALTIME (on any operating system btw, not just Windows).

Comment: Thanks. That is the most common answer I found during my research on this topic. I still wonder how I can achieve a similar scheduling behaviour on windows to what I already have on the mac. And what about media streaming, e.g. audio/video?
Any ideas on the policy of boost::threads?

Comment: Media streaming may be among the very few programs that have somewhat of a justification for "slightly higher" priority, so they don't stutter under concurrency. But generally, all available CPU time will be used by a "normal priority" task (and by a "low priority" one as well, only after everyone else was served!), so there is no benefit in higher priorities. It can on the other hand seriously interfere with services that really **need** to react with little delay. If you tamper with it, you may experience that suddenly the mouse or the disk isn't working properly any more.

Comment: Getting similar scheduling behavior as on another system is impossible, since the schedulers simply don't work that way. Unix-like systems (so... Mac or Linux) give each thread CPU time, and a bit less to "nicer" threads. Windows gives everything to the group of highest priority ready threads, until it is completely satisfied. Then, and only then, it serves the next class. This is _very_ different behavior. There's no way to change that either, it's just how the scheduler works.

Comment: @Damon - Windows does have an anti-starvation algorithm but, sure, Windows/Linux scheduling algorithms are different.